# Weird iPython Notebook figure size behavior

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, figure

I'm seeing a strange effect in iPython Notebook that I don't understand. If I place the following code in a singe cell and run it twice, both times the figure will be plotted with my custom figure size specification.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8,6)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1],[1,2])
```

Now if I create a file called `set_figsize.py` that contains the following lines:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 6.0)
```

and start a new notebook with the following in a single cell:

```
%matplotlib inline
import set_figsize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1],[1,2])
```

and run that twice, the first time the figure is plotted with my custom figure size, and the second time it's back to the smaller default size. If I place `%matplotlib inline` in an individual cell and only run that once, my custom figure size remains in place. So it seems like every time I run `%matplotlib inline` the figure size is set to the default, but running `import set_figsize` only takes effect the first time I run it. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of a module is only actually *run* the first time it gets imported. This is necessary to prevent double definitions of functions and classes and so on, and also to allow circular imports (when two modules both import each other).

When you `import set_figsize` the second time, Python checks in `sys.modules` and sees that there is already a module object imported under the name `set_figsize`, so it just uses that object. It doesn't run the file again.

As a consequence, it's a good rule in most cases that you should only put *definitions* in modules. Don't put in statements with side effects that you expect to run when the module is imported. If you want to write a Python *script*, one which you can execute from the command line (`python script.py`), put everything that's not a definition or import under an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.